# Non-blocking (NIO) reading of lines

Tags: java, file, nio

I need to read a file line by line using `java.nio`, but `nio` doesn't have a method like `readline()` to read one, complete line at a time. What solutions are there?

Comment: Why do you need to do this with Java NIO; do you think this will gain you something above using `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @Jesper yes .. can u please tell me how to read a line like .readline()

Comment: a sample code will help greatly

Comment: Let me rephrase: **what** do you think you will gain by using NIO instead of `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Using readLine on a Socket http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577719/java-sockets-bufferedreader-and-readline-hang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788250/java-efficiency-of-the-readline-method-of-the-bufferedreader-and-possible-alter

Comment: @Jesper i want to compare .. cAsual r&d .. can u give me a snippet for reading line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NIO is typically used to do either direct memory access or block mediated bulk data transfers.  It does do other things, but other features have more to do with blocking and non-blocking data access.

As such, you might want to use NIO to grab the data quickly (or in a non-blocking manner); however, if you want to "read line by line" you would be better served by doing the line detection after NIO has read in the available data.  This could easily be implemented by putting a "line reading" facade over the buffer that NIO just read.

Comment: "putting a "line reading" facade over the buffer that NIO just read"

Comment: No answer is going to be forthcoming, as while you dig deeper into how to do this, it just begins to become more heavily dependent on a lot of small items (how you are processing the NIO buffers).  Of course, you can always then use the NIO buffers to back a stream based reader; but that raises the question, why did you use NIO then?

Answer (score 17):

I understand you guys don't like limitations, but in case the one asking don't have access to IO package or not allowed to import it for some reason the top answer is not helpful...

Two ways to do it completely IO free:

1. `java.nio.file.Files.lines` ,
   Returns a stream of lines, which is part of .util package and not .io package like bufferedReader.
2. `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines`  ,
   Returns a collection of lines which is iterable. 
   Proceed to use an `iterator` or`for each` to extract a single line.

cheers

Comment: 'In case the one asking doesn't have access to IO package' is a completely imaginary constraint.

Comment: @EJP College exercises have weird constraints sometimes.

Comment: @user207421nope. Today I find myself in the same situation and it's how Daniel Braun said

Comment: Both of the methods you alluded to (`Files.lines` and `Files.readAllLines`) are actually implemented using a `java.io.BufferedReader`.  So I'm not sure how that's useful to the OP, who, as far as I can tell wanted to use non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 5):

Why? NIO doesn't support reading lines. You can read millions of lines a second with `BufferedReader.readLine().` I suggest that is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle introduces a example in the tutorial.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#streams

```
Path file = ...;
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader =
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) you can do:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/path/to", "file.txt");
Files.lines(path).forEach(line ->
    // consume line
);
```

As the `lines(path)` method returns a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you can take advantage of any other method of the Stream API, like reading just the first line (if one exists) with:

```
Optional<String> firstLine = Files.lines(path).findFirst();
```

Comment: If you look at the source code, `Files.lines()` is implemented using a plain old `BufferedReader`, so you still have old-fashioned blocking IO.  By the way, `BufferedReader` also has a `lines()` method which allows using it with the `Stream` API.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me....

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile
                ("F:\\DetailsMy1.txt", "r");
        FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0)
        {
            buffer.flip();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
            {
                char ch = ((char) buffer.get());
                if(ch=='\r'){
                    System.out.print(line+"[EOL]");
                    line=new StringBuffer();
                }else{
                    line.append(ch);
                }
            }
            buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
        }
        inChannel.close();
        aFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this code defeat the purpose of using java.nio.  You are reading one byte at a time.

Comment: And you are avoiding the issue of character-sets altogether.

Comment: This is a perfect example why such code is a bad idea. You have a bug there. The last line stays in line StringBuffer without being printed or otherewise processed.

Answer (score 1):

In support of EJP and others above, you might reference this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078654/java-se/java-se-five-ways-to-maximize-java-nio-and-nio-2.html

In particular: 
"While NIO is often promoted for its performance advantages, it's more precise to say it is highly responsive. In some cases NIO actually performs worse than basic Java I/O. For simple sequential reads and writes of small files, for instance, a straightforward streams implementation might be two or three times faster than the corresponding event-oriented channel-based coding. Also, non-multiplexed channels -- that is, channels in separate threads -- can be much slower than channels that register their selectors in a single thread."

I would highlight the statement that NIO ***In some cases [...] performs worse than basic Java I/O***. The author follows up with a list of questions to drive a quick analysis of whether NIO is the right choice. If you (or the next person to come along) still decides to pursue NIO there is a good  explanation of its use with code example.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could convert a BufferedReader to a Stream using the lines method

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());    
}
```

2) Get a Stream directly using the Files.lines method:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream
        .filter(s -> s.endswith("/"))
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

As DanielBraun points out in his answer, you could also use the readAllLines method instead of the lines method, difference being, straight from the docs:

> Unlike readAllLines, this method does not read all lines into a List,
>   but instead populates lazily as the stream is consumed.

The [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) page from Java docs gives a nice and concise overview about Streams, and this [article](https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-java/) also lists out a few other ways of reading a file by line in Java.

Answer (score -1):

simply use:
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

EDIT (humanreadable translation, regards to MeetTitan): Which means: use `java.nio.file.Files.lines(Path)` - it returns a `Stream<String>` representing the lines of the file. It's an method provided by the Java API. One could consult the Javadoc in order to see the details. The most relevant information is therefore: `Files.lines()` exists since Java 1.8. Use it.